# Low entropy transfer function, output impedance

Tags: transfer-function

I am trying to understand and apply the concept of low entropy transfer functions as outlined by C.Basso and equally stated by a couple of people here.

As an example, I wanted to work through an L-C 2nd order filter feeding a load

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fil8QB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Working through the example makes sense as the L and C are shorted or opened to quickly determine the tau of the associated elements to finally combine to produce the overall transfer function \$\frac{V_o}{V_{in}}\$

What I am trying to do is then determine the current transfer function \$\frac{I_o}{I_n}\$ as well as the input and output impedance but it's clear I haven't fully grasped this concept. Likewise, \$R_3\$ is my load and it is a constant power load so the impedance will vary. This was briefly covered in the book but only in passing.

Could someone help guide me in determining the current gain, the \$Z_{in}\$ and \$Z_{out}\$ following the EET method

Comment: I'm currently reading his book but I would leave it C.Basso himself :)

Comment: @Verbal Kint should help you

Comment: If you take the Norton equivalent cct of V1,rl,L then you can compute the I(R3) using Laplace if each branch if you know the initial conditions.

Comment: What is EET? Avoid non-std. Acronyms

Comment: To get \$Z_{out}\$, simply short the input source \$V_1\$ and you end-up having three elements in parallel: \$L_1\$ and its series resistance, your load (which is a **fixed** value at the considered operating point) and capacitor \$C_2\$ with its ESR. Determine the time constants for the denominator \$D(s)\$ then the zeros for the numerator \$N(s)\$. The dc gain \$R_0\$ is \$R_3\$. For more details, please check my APEC 2016 seminar on FACTs (slide 90) http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm where I detail the procedure.

Comment: @VerbalKint Best make that an answer, I'm willing to bet others might have similar queries in the future. :-)

Comment: @a concerned citizen, sure, done, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: ijuneja, EET is the "Extra Element Theorem".

Answer (score 1):

To get \$Z_{out}\$, simply short the input source \$V_1\$ and you end-up having three elements in parallel: \$L_1\$ and its series resistance, your load (which is a fixed value at the considered operating point) and capacitor \$C_2\$ with its ESR. Determine the time constants for the denominator \$D(s)\$ then the zeros for the numerator \$N(s)\$. The dc gain \$R_0\$ is \$R_3||r_L\$. For more details, please check my APEC 2016 seminar on [FACTs](http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf) (slide 90) where I detail the procedure.